# Фиксированная шапка у таблицы не совпадает с колонками (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Сделал таблицу с прокруткой и растяжением по ширине.
Одна проблема - фиксированные заголовки таблицы не совпадают по ширине с колонками.
Как достичь результата, чтобы все растягивалось ровно, как в Экселе.

```css
.table-fixed-head {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100vh;
   }

.table-fixed-head th,
.table-fixed-head td {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.333vw;
}

.table-fixed-head thead {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display:table;
  
}

.table-fixed-head thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.table-fixed-head tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 700px);
}

.table-fixed-head tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ааа;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-fixed-head table-bordered ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
      <td>2323232</td>
      <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
      <td>0211621</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>23232</td>
      <td>223232</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Как минимум, добавить ячейкам _word-break: break-all;_, потому что длинный текст растягивает ячейку независимо от того, какую ширину Вы задали. Но будет ещё проблема с шириной скролл-бара (в шапке-то его нет). Придётся выдумывать "костыли" :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю Вам рассмотреть вариант с внутренними независимыми друг от друга таблицами: в одну помещаете заголовки, а в другую - содержимое ячеек:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  width: 4.667%;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
th:nth-of-type(2),
th:nth-of-type(4),
th:nth-of-type(6),
.tbody-wrap td:nth-of-type(2),
.tbody-wrap td:nth-of-type(4),
.tbody-wrap td:nth-of-type(6){
  width: 10%;
}
.thead-wrap {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: pink;
}
.tbody-wrap {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tbody-wrap tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="18">
      <div class="thead-wrap">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="18">
        <div class="tbody-wrap">
          <table>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Наименование будет раскрываться</td>
                <td>2323232</td>
                <td>1Рвыпвлыгнвефпывфывфывфывфывфы</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>ОРРвывоывыворыоврыв</td>
                <td>0211621</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>122</td>
                <td>23232</td>
                <td>223232</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ну, да. Осталось только дать возможность колонкам оптимально подстраиваться под ширину данных в ячейках. И отслеживать изменения содержимого таблицы с помощью MutationObserver, приводя ширину заголовков в соответствие с соответствующими колонками.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, без относительно моего решения: каким образом Вы себе представляете "возможность колонкам оптимально подстраиваться под ширину данных в ячейках"? Это данные должны подстраиваться под ширину ячейки.

Comment: Обычно во всех примерах с зафиксированными заголовками таблицы у ячеек с данными жестко задана ширина (или высота, если заголовки в первом столбце). Это вынужденная мера, потому что заголовки не связаны с ячейками данных, не растягиваются вместе с ними.

Но часто бывает нужно дать ячейкам самим распределить между собой доступное пространство таблицы (обычное поведение html-таблицы)

Comment: А как быть с ячейками, где будет текст. Символов около 200-300? Кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Используя ваш вариант, можно ли сделать так: Определенные ячейки будут фиксированной ширины, остальные адаптируются? Я знаю точно, что некоторые ячейки будут содержать 5 символов, другие 8 либо 10.

Comment: @LEX, а в чём проблема с текстом? Ячейкам же можно задать разную ширину, не обязательно одинаковую. Просто разные проценты, чтобы в сумме получилось 100. Там, где текст, имеет смысл пошире сделать, а где-то поуже.

Comment: Подскажите, как это сделать в процентах? Я новичок в фронтенде.

Comment: @LEX, так Вы мой код посмотрите - у меня сейчас ширина в процентах задана. Там, где текст, 10% (таких 3 колонки). Остальные 70% я поделил между оставшимися 15-ю колонками. В принципе можно каждой колонке задать свою собственную ширину. Главное, чтобы в сумме проценты не превышали 100.